# Read/Write to proc entry from user space

Tags: c, linux, fwrite, kernel-module

I have a LKM module which creates a proc entry using create_proc_entry(). I have to send some complex data (I am thinking of a structure) from user space program and store it in the /proc entry so that the LKM can receive it.

Right now, I am puzzled on how to convert structure data into buffered output using something like fwrite() because the callback for write from user space to /proc entry has the data argument in form of a buffer.

```
 // fwrite prototype
 size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );

 // user space write to /proc entry call back prototype
 int mod_write( struct file *filp, const char __user *buff,
  unsigned long len, void *data );
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your safest bet is to write it the relevant info out as text. That prevents endianness issues, increases flexibility and makes debugging much easier.

Comment: @larsmans, Endianness shouldn't be an issue within the sane machine. Flexibility is debatable - if adding a struct member means writing conversion from/to text, it isn't so flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply write the data. Something like this:

```
struct my_data s = { initialization... };
fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, stream);
fflush(stream);
```

Then `mod_write` would get a pointer to `s` and would copy it into kernel space.
You may also use `write`, and then you won't need to flush it.

If your structure contains pointers, things get more complicated.

Comment: My structure does contain pointers, what needs to be done in that case ?